# Running a program on a 64bit and 32bit system

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit

Is there any reason why a c++ program that runs perfectly on a 64 bit system crashes on a 32 bit system? I have a program tested on 2 servers. one a 64bit and other 32bit. The program doesnt have bit specific commands. Initially it was working in both until i made a chage and added a structure and called it. The program crashed when this structure object was called for the first time. But if i print the value of the elements 1 line before the crash it, the values are there. Btw, the by value i mean integers and no pointers or other funny stuff.
I tried initiating these integers as uint32_t and such experiments. But to meet a dead end.

the structure is like this

```
struct info {
    int id1, id2;
    string test;
};

map<string, info> allInfo
vector<string> temp;
/* temp populated */

info details = {atoi(temp[0].c_str()),atoi(temp[2].c_str()),temp[3].c_str()};
allInfo[temp[1].c_str()] = details; 

/*somewhere after this it is accessed */

map<string, info>::iterator i;
/* printing the values here seems ok.. */
cout << (*i).second.id1 << endl << (*i).second.id2 << endl;
string first_id = "idOne : " + (*i).second.id1; 
string second_id = "idTwo: " + (*i).second.id2;
```

Comment: What's the error when it crashes?

Comment: it just segfaults.. no error displayed..

Comment: what os? for linux do you have a core file?

Comment: @Prasanth: Have you tried running it in a debugger?

Comment: Is it the same executable or two different executables?

Comment: @Peter Alexander : the 32bit server doesnt have gdb and i dont have admin rights. so thats why i posted here maybe some answer will be it..

Comment: @AProgrammer : 2 executables. i compiled it on each server separately.

Comment: @Prasanth, you don't need to be admin to install gdb.

Comment: yeah well.. no sudo for me if thats what you mean...

Comment: @prasanth, I mean exactly what I wrote: you don't need to be root to compile gdb from sources and use it.

Comment: Is it the same binary (32 bit), working on one architecture and not on the other OR two binaries (32 and 64 bits), one of each is not working?

Comment: Is `map<string, info>::iterator i;` initialized?

Comment: What he means is, that you only declare the iterator i without assigning any start value like allInfo.begin() or so. Maybe you just did not post it in the code snippet.

Comment: yes..  didnot post it in the code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's multiple things that could go wrong, and without a debugger it's going to be a nightmare to find out.

Option 1: Convince whoever has admin rights to the server to install `gdb`.

Option 2: Add print statements everywhere to figure out exactly which line the segfault occurs on a post it here (or try and figure it out from that on your own).

Comment: crashes right after accessing an integer inside a structure. i used signal(SIGSEGV, sig_segv) this to find out. as you can guess, i cant put the code here... so i am kinda stuck.. :(

Comment: That probably means that the pointer to the structure that you're accessing the integer from is NULL, or otherwise invalid. Have a look where that pointer comes from.

Comment: no pointer used. and the integers are fine.. i mean i printed them just before the crash and they have their values.

Comment: @Prasanth: Can you post the code of how you are using that structure, and how you are printing its values?

Answer (score 0):

A simple reason would be Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess. Did you compile it on/for 64bit machines?
It may be that there is some opcode in there that is not available in 32bit machines.

Comment: then could you give the source of the structure that introduced the error?

Answer (score 0):

So no cast, no dynamic allocation and a crash in 32 bit build and not in 64 bit build.  My first guess would be accessing an array outside their range.

Comment: crashes right after accessing an integer inside a structure. i used signal(SIGSEGV, sig_segv) this to find out. as you can guess, i cant put the code here... so i am kinda stuck.. :(

Answer (score 0):

you're adding integers to char-arrays in:

```
string first_id = "idOne : " + (*i).second.id1; 
string second_id = "idTwo: " + (*i).second.id2;
```

may be you're test-sets differs and on the non-throwing system you accidently get a valid address to assign to the string variable.